# How to include an attribute in an XPath selection

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I am using selenium to move through the pages.

Following is the page source:

```
<td colspan="10" align="right">
                <input type="button" name="previous" value="Previous" onclick="this.form.action = 'coca-cola-north-america-group-company-37452.htm?previous=true&currentPage=6';this.form.submit();" > 
                <input type="hidden" name="currentPage" id="currentPage" value="6" />

                <input type="button" name="next" value="Next" onclick="this.form.action = 'coca-cola-north-america-group-company-37452.htm?next=true&currentPage=6';this.form.submit();" >
            </td>


<td colspan="10" align="right">
                <input type="button" name="previous" value="Previous" onclick="this.form.action = 'coca-cola-north-america-group-company-37452.htm?previous=true&currentPage=7';this.form.submit();" > 
                <input type="hidden" name="currentPage" id="currentPage" value="7" />
```

I am using seleniums click method to click the next page,

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@name="next"]').click()
```

Now when I come to the last page (below is the source code) I get the same xpath (for next page link)--- with attribute `disabled` at the end. And I want selenium to stop here.

However I am not sure how to include the `disabled` attribute in the xpath.

```
                <input type="button" name="next" value="Next" onclick="this.form.action = 'coca-cola-north-america-group-company-37452.htm?next=true&currentPage=7';this.form.submit();" disabled>
            </td>
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Try:

```
//*[@name="next"][not(@disabled)]
```